# C "double free or corruption" error

Tags: c, memory, free, allocation, corruption

This the short code, that produces a `double free or corruption` error.

```
SDL_Surface *surface;
SDL_Surface *surface2;
surface = NULL;
surface2 = SDL_LoadBMP("someImg.bmp");
surface = surface2;
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface2);
```

I don't understand, why I can't free second surface before I free first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both variables `surface` and `surface2` point to the same object. You are effectively freeing twice the same object.

Comment: Do you know how to assign only content, without address?

Comment: @Davey: There might be an SDL API to clone `SDL_Surface` objects.  You could also load the bitmap twice.  Copying the structures will most likely not work either.

Comment: @Davey: you don't copy *content* at all when you assign. As `SDL_Surface` is a type of the SDL library and has a link to an internal struct, you can't copy it yourself, but you can create a new matching surface with `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` and copy the data there with `SDL_BlitSurface()`.

Comment: @Davey you could also `memcpy()` the pixel data to a buffer you `malloc()` yourself and then use `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom()`. In that case, `SDL_FreeSurface()` will *not* free your pixel data, you must call `free()` on it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

By running the `surface = surface2;` statement, you're making both the `surface` and `surface2` pointers point to the same region of memory. Once you've freed it, it's free. Trying to free it again (via the other pointer), will attempt to free already freed memory, causing this error.